# Extract text from a dynamic web-page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, web

My need is if I'm given an URL of a web-page I've to extract all the text from that. Now there is case for web pages which loads further when you do scrolled-down them to the end like fb timeline. How could I extract text from those web-page programatically ? Any ideas/example ?

Comment: please add comment if someone votes down.

Comment: If cross domain, you need to proxified it server side but internal js won't be executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's getting more complicated to get dynamically loaded content from a webpage.

One suggestion is, to open your browsers developer panel and take a look at the network tab. If you can decipher the logic behind the AJAX calls, then you could call these URLs on your own, for example with PHPs `file_get_contents`. Something like `http://url.com/morecontent.php?offset=20`.

Another suggestion is to use a headless browser like phantom.js which contains an own javascript engine and can be controlled programatically - http://phantomjs.org/

Answer (score -2):

You can use cURL. Here is the example code.

[Get data or Content from a URL using cURL PHP](http://phpcodeforbeginner.blogspot.in/2013/01/get-data-or-content-from-url-using-curl.html)

Comment: This will not help with dynamic data.